# Which PyTorch version is CUDA compute capability 3.0 compatible?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 770, which is CUDA compute capability 3.0, but upon running PyTorch training on the GPU, I get the warning

```
Found GPU0 GeForce GTX 770 which is of cuda capability 3.0.
PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
The minimum cuda capability that we support is 3.5.
```

and subsequently the error `RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device`.

Was there an old PyTorch version, that supported graphics cards like mine with CUDA capability 3.0? If yes, which version, and where to find this information? Is there a table somewhere, where I can find the supported CUDA versions and compatibility versions?

If it is relevant, I have CUDA 10.1 installed.

Comment: CUDA capability 3.0 support was dropped in [v0.3.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.3.1) so you would need to use something older than that. You would be installing a pretty old version of pytorch, most code from newer pytorch wouldn't work there.

Comment: I agree, that the question can seem off-topic, but it is directly related to software development (running software on the GPU rather than CPU) and a tool (PyTorch) that is primarily used for programming. My graphics card is just an example. Similar questions have been asked several times in the PyTorch forums, but the unstructured format makes it really hard to get an answer from there. But if it helps, then this question could be migrated to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch 0.3.0 was the [last version](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.3.1) to support CUDA compute capability 3.0.

Alternatively, you could [compile PyTorch from source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source) (which may still support this, I haven't verified).