# Getting CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device on windows 10 python 3.8

Tags: pytorch, cuda, nvidia, python-3.8, torchvision

I am using windows 10 system which has python 3.8 64 bit, NVIDIA GeForce GT 710.

I am trying to run segment-anything model published by meta https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/blob/main/notebooks/predictor_example.ipynb

But I keep getting the error RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Below are my system setting and other dependencies:

```
PyTorch version: 1.8.1+cu111
Torchvision version: 0.9.1+cu111
CUDA is available: True
```

Output of the command "nvidia-smi"

```
NVIDIA-SMI 456.71       Driver Version: 456.71       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 710     WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   43C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    565MiB /  2048MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

nvcc --version command gives the following output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Feb__8_05:53:42_Coordinated_Universal_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0
```

Python version

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Code (line masks = mask_generator.generate(image) gives the error):

```
import torch
import torchvision
import sys
import numpy as np
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import gc
import os
import argparse
from typing import Any, Dict, List
from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, SamPredictor
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("PyTorch version:", torch.__version__)
    print("Torchvision version:", torchvision.__version__)
    print("CUDA is available:", torch.cuda.is_available())

    sam_checkpoint = "sam_vit_l_0b3195.pth"
    model_type = "vit_l"
    device = "cuda"

    sam = sam_model_registry[model_type](checkpoint=sam_checkpoint)
    sam.to(device=device)
    mask_generator = SamAutomaticMaskGenerator(sam)

    image = cv2.imread('C:/dog.jpg')
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    # plt.imshow(image)
    # plt.axis('off')
    # plt.show()

    masks = mask_generator.generate(image)
```

Can anyone help me fix this please

Comment: Your GT 710 GPU is too old to be reasonably useful with any modern DL software stacks including recent versions of pytorch.  A GT 710 GPU is either compute capability 2.x or 3.0.  Yours is probably cc 3.0  Even compute capability 3.0 is not supported by CUDA 11 or pytorch.  You've also evidently installed CUDA 12.1 which won't work with your installed driver, but that is besides the point.  Your GPU is too old.  If you want to beat your head against the wall, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62437918/which-pytorch-version-is-cuda-3-0-compatible).